# How do I prevent a form object from disposing on close?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, formclosing

I am using an MDIParent Form. When I close its child, the object of the child disposes. Is there a way to set child visibility to false instead of disposing?

Comment: Override the close event that handles this.  Of course if this is done then you have stuff memory which just cannot be seen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding MDI Child Forms on Close C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020210/hiding-mdi-child-forms-on-close-c)

Comment: All the answers here are missing the magic sauce. If you just handle the `FormClosing` event without a special case, you'll never be able to close the application. Whoops! That's probably not what you or the user intended. The code in my answer to the above-linked duplicate question is correct, though, and works without a hitch in both circumstances.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default, when you close a form, it will be disposed. You have to override the `Closing` event to prevent it, for example:

```
// Use this event handler for the FormClosing event.
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  e.Cancel = true; // this cancels the close event.
}
```

Comment: This is only true if the form was shown using the Show method.  If the form is shown with ShowDialog, then it is not automatically disposed.

Comment: I've already applied this to my form, but visual components `Dispose` functions are called anyway. It only helps, not to close form.

Comment: Another thing to know, you can inspect `e.CloseReason` to determine if the user or the application called the `Form`'s `Close` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can cancel the close event and hide instead.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: This is the opposite order of calls compared to the accepted answer. Does the order matter?

Comment: No, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can call the form's "Hide" method.

You can also override OnClosed and not call its base implementation; HOWEVER, when you DO want to dispose of the form, this may get in your way.

Comment: I don't think so. When you override the Closed event, it's too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can cancel the close and hide it. It doesn't seem like a good thing to do, but you definitely can.

See *[Form.FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)* (MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

```
    void SaveInfo()
{
blnCanCloseForm = false;
Vosol[] vs = getAdd2DBVosol();
if (DGError.RowCount > 0)
return;

Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
{
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    picLoad.Visible = true;
    lblProcces.Text = "Saving ...";
});
int intError = setAdd2DBVsosol(vs);
Action action = (() =>
{
    if (intError > 0)
    {
        objVosolError = objVosolError.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
        DGError.DataSource = objVosolError;// dtErrorDup.DefaultView;
        DGError.Refresh();
        DGError.Show();
        lblMSG.Text = "Check Errors...";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Saved All Records...");
        blnCanCloseForm = true;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

});
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    picLoad.Visible = false;
    lblProcces.Text = "";
});
this.BeginInvoke(action);
});
myThread.Start();
}

void frmExcellImportInfo_FormClosing(object s, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!blnCanCloseForm)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```