# Error when calling Form.Show() a second time

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I have a main form with a button.

OnClick of that button does the following...

```
Form AllBook = new Form();
//Does some other processing and SQLReader querying.
AllBook.Show();
```

Afterwards I close the form.  When I try to show it again I receive this error.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Form'.'

```
// objects
Form AllBook        = new Form();
ComboBox booksList  = new ComboBox();
ComboBox chapters   = new ComboBox();
Panel topPannel     = new Panel();
Panel txtPannel     = new Panel();
TextBox mainText    = new TextBox();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add objects to form
    AllBook.Controls.Add(topPannel);
    topPannel.Controls.Add(booksList);

    // get combobox items from another Method
    int chapterCount = countChapters(43);
        for (int i = 1; i <= chapterCount; i++) {
            chapters.Items.Add(i);
        }

    topPannel.Controls.Add(chapters);
    AllBook.Controls.Add(txtPannel);

    txtPannel.Controls.Add(mainText);

    AllBook.Show();
}

// count books chapters
public int countChapters(int bookNum) {
     int chapter = 0;
     switch (bookNum) {
         case 1:
            chapter = 50;
              break;
              case 2:
            chapter = 40;
              break;
              case 3:
            chapter = 27;
              break;
              case 4:
            chapter = 36;
              break;
        .....
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how you “close Form & again open AllBook form”.

Comment: If you close a form `AllBooks.Close`, the form is disposed. To use it again you have to create a new one or use `Hide`instead of `Close`.

Comment: Call this `AllBook = new Form();` every time you click the button.

Comment: Why do you programmatically build the form? Just use the windows forms designer so it doesn't look a mess and then make a new instance every time you want to show the form

Comment: 'cause I want a program for low ram capacity computer

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen , nothing change

Answer (score 0):

@H.G. Sandhagen and @LarsTech are correct.

Closing should dispose of the form.  If you want to show it again you need to...

```
Form AllBook = new Form();
AllBook.Show();
```

...every time.

Edit: Adding further clarification.
Closing the form in a way calls Disopose() as well.

Source:

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your
>   application, your application ends.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I wanted to do that but -- AllBook_closeForm() -- not working for me. so I can not dispose form on closing it.

Comment: @user2215032 I added clarification.  AllBook.Close() automatically calls AllBook.Dispose().  You can disable that if you want.  Instructions are in the link in my answer.

Comment: just do AllBooks.Hide instead of close

Comment: @pm100 you would still have to create a close event on the form and set the Cancel property.  The link to the Microsoft article details it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

By default, closing a form will dispose it. But you can change this behavior by [overriding the Closing event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060562/87399).

So you should either:

- Create a new instance of your form each time you show it, and allow WinForms to dispose it when the user closes it; or
- Override the Closing event, so that closing causes the form to get hidden instead of disposed, at which point you'll be able to show the same form multiple times:

  ```
  private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      Hide();
      e.Cancel = true;
  }
  ```

Note that if you choose the second option, it will be up to you to call `Dispose()` on the form when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is closing it automatically gets disposed, So you can refresh it before showing it again by using:

```
   Allbook.Refresh();
```