# System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' when Hiding button

Tags: c#, winforms

After years with the same code, suddenly I am fighting with this randomly appearing parameter that is not a valid error on many of my buttons. It started with the errors appearing on buttons that I had background images on, after removing the images the errors on those buttons stopped sporadically appearing. Now that I thought I had this issue fixed, this confirms button that I have to hide after clicking (and obviously showing again after an item is selected) is sporadically dropping this error. This has been the same exact code for literal years now. Never have had an issue. There is no image on this button, I do change the text on it every time an item is selected and I do.Show(). I can use this 150 times, and it will do it on the 151st, it is completely random, with no pattern whatsoever.

When the exception happens, it is stopping on the btnConfirm.Hide(); line in my C#, even when it is inside a try-catch now, it still gives me an exception unhandled.

Here are the exception details:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Flags()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.IsImageTransparent(Image backgroundImage)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I will also add, these are pretty much identical to the exception details I was getting from the buttons with images on them. The only difference with those was I was doing nothing with them in the code, it would just randomly drop the exception in the middle of working with the form.

Comment: How and where are you adding these images to the buttons? Can you create a [mre] that we can play with? Otherwise we have to guess and while some of us are pretty good at that future visitors of your question might have a hard time recognizing they have the same issue from just a stacktrace.

Comment: You get there when [GdipGetImageFlags()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-image-flat) returns a `GPSTATUS = 2`. Different conditions may cause this, the most obvious is when the Image's Handle is invalid. I.e., you have to post the code that generates the exception

Comment: Like I said, this button does not have an image on it. I should also specify, when I had the images on all the buttons, I at one point got a out of memory error as well. So I had safely assumed it was a memory issue. Only after I removed all the images and cleaned that issue up did this imageless button start giving me this error sporadically. I'm still questioning if it may be a memory issue on the form in some way shape or form...

Comment: So to further clarify this specific issue, this error is sporadically appearing when calling .Hide() on a button.

Comment: When you see System.Drawing.Image back in the exception stack trace then you must assume the exception is generated by the Image class.  It is not a button, the Button class does not derive from ScrollableControl.  Could be, for example, a form or panel with a BackgroundImage.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection happens at random. If your images are loaded and there is no reference to the images, then possibly they are being disposed, or some place in your code is disposing them.

The following code produces the same error message.

```
    try {
        Image someImage = Image.FromFile(...);
        someImage.Dispose();
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(ControlPaint).GetMethod("IsImageTransparent", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        mi.Invoke(null, new Object[] { someImage });
    } catch {
    }
```

Comment: Like I said, this button does not have an image on it. I should also specify, when I had the images on all the buttons, I at one point got a out of memory error as well. So I had safely assumed it was a memory issue. Only after I removed all the images and cleaned that issue up did this imageless button start giving me this error sporadically. I'm still questioning if it may be a memory issue on the form in some way shape or form...

Comment: So to further clarify this specific issue, this error is sporadically appearing when calling .Hide() on a button.

Comment: @ItsChase  I didn't say your buttons had images on them. The stack trace is showing the error is coming from a `ScrollableControl` object.  As for `Out of Memory` error, it is a common misleading error message when dealing with images. For example, trying to use the `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` will often result in an `Out of Memory` exception.

Comment: If you are using `Form form= ...; form.ShowDialog();` and recreating the form each time, the issue could be disposing the form object, which is disposing other objects. You may want to reuse the same form object, and instead of closing it, just hide it. E.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060471/how-do-i-prevent-a-form-object-from-disposing-on-close

Comment: It has been a long day, but I have fixed it. As I was suspecting due to the random nature and the fact the code has been working without issue for years now prior to this randomly starting, something deeper must've been messed up. I decided to go ahead and migrate from VS19 to 22, and in turn .Net Framework 4.7.2 to 6.0. Using the identical code and designer.cs layouts that I copied over, it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this may not be the expected direction of an answer, but I spent my entire day migrating from VS19 to VS22 with a newly created WinForms project. This includes a move from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to 6.0. After copying all of my code and designer.cs over, the program is running flawlessly as it has for years. Genuinely no idea what was causing the issue, but whatever it was is staying back in VS19/.Net 4.7.2.